# Word VBA help- Insert carriage return after images

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of images in a Word doc that I am using the following script to resize.  Is there a way for me to insert a carriage return after each image?  I would ideally need double spacing after each image.  I am using the script below to resize the images.

```
Sub ResizePhotos()
    Dim pic As InlineShape

    For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        With pic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Height = InchesToPoints(3.33)
                .Width = InchesToPoints(4.44)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An InlineShape has a Range object that represents its location in the document. Working with this we can improve on Martin's answer with the following:

```
Dim pic As Word.InlineShape

For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With pic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = InchesToPoints(3.33)
        .Width = InchesToPoints(4.44)
        .Range.Style = "Your Style Name"
    End With
Next
```

Or if you really need to add the extra paragraph:

```
For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With pic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = InchesToPoints(3.33)
        .Width = InchesToPoints(4.44)
        .Range.InsertAfter Chr(13)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

An awful solution, but I thought I'd post it anyway:

I added a button to the document which I want to perform the action on. I then assigned the following macro to the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim pic As InlineShape


For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    pic.Select
    Selection.EscapeKey
    SendKeys "{down}"
    Selection.Text = Chr(13)
Next

End Sub
```

This selects each image, escapes the selection. Moves to the next line with a keypress (though, I'm sure this can be done 'programmatically') and then inserts a carriage return.

Please treat this as an idea, i'm sure the method above can break in many, many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding one or several carriage return after images, consider the following:

1. define a style in your document, similar to the ones normally used for headings (see the image below) that has the attributes you want for your `InlineShapes`, or their paragraphs more precisely. For example

   - centered
   - with a 18pt spacing below the "paragraph"
2. save your style as `yourStyleFormat`
3. adjust your code in a similar fashion

   ```
   Dim pic As Word.InlineShape

   For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
       With pic
           .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
           .Height = InchesToPoints(3.33)
           .Width = InchesToPoints(4.44)
           .Select
           Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("yourStyleFormat")
       End With
   Next
   ```

Pros:

- this doesn't add empty rows to your document, which is a no-no
- you can edit the general layout of all your pictures by simply editing the style

Cons:

- Using `Select` is ugly. I used it since I couldnt figure out how to apply a `.Style` to a `InlineShape`. Therefore, I tread the picture as paragraph by selecting it first. Im sure there's a more elegant way to access the images parent-paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this wil help someone special

```
Sub rezize_center_newline()

Dim i As Long
Dim shpIn As InlineShape, shp As Shape

With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .Height = InchesToPoints(4)
            .Width = InchesToPoints(5.32)
            .Range.InsertAfter Chr(13)
        End With
    Next i
    For Each shpIn In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        shpIn.Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Next shpIn
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        shp.Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Next shp
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I just created this macro, and it which works quite well. I repeated the content many times, so that it would do the search and replace on many images. Hope it's useful:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^g"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeParagraph


End Sub
```